# ROS topic is not published yet

Tags: ros, rospy

I have this code which receives data from node (subscribe) and then inside this node I do some
mathematical operation, then I want to publish the data to a certain topic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String, Float32
from math import cos,sin

import sys
import os
import logging
from types import *
import time

class exact_pose():

    def callback_car_yaw(self, data):
        self.car_yaw = data

    def callback_line_pose(self,data):
        self.line_pose = data

        
    def init(self):
      
 
        self.car_yaw = None
        self.line_pose = None
      

    def subscriber(self):
        
 
            
        self.car_yaw_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~car/yaw',Float32, self.callback_car_yaw)
            
        self.line_pose_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~line_pose',Float32, self.callback_line_detect_xL15)

    def publisher(self):

        self.exact_pose_pub = rospy.Publisher('exact_pose',Float32, queue_size=10)
        

        rospy.Rate(1)
        rospy.spin()
      
      
        #sloving for exact pose 

    def calculation(self,):
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():

            self.exact_pose = self.line_pose_sub * cos(self.car_yaw_sub) + self.line_pose_sub * sin(self.car_yaw_sub)
            info1 = Float32()
            info1.data = self.exact_pose
            self.exact_pose_pub.publish(info1)


            rospy.Rate.sleep()
            rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('exact_pose', anonymous=True)
    try:
      ne = exact_pose()

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

so what the code does, subscribe to a topic from a previous node, then do some mathematical operation for these data inside the topics, then publish the last result on separate Node

Comment: What do you mean by "not appear". Can you describe the problem you experience with your code in more detail?

Comment: when I run "rostopic echo /exact_pose"

I received this message in the terminal 
"topic [/exact_pose] does not appear to be published yet"

Comment: So as soon as you run the node and then open another console, source the workspace and then run `rostopic echo` you get this error message?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When requiring asynchronous communication, like in subscribers, multiple threads running in parallel will have to be involved.
ROS uses [callbacks](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) in order to hide multi-threading required for subscribers from its users. When a new message arrives these callbacks will be added to a callback queue (whose maximum size can be defined for each publisher/subscriber) and then be processed. The way this works differs between C++ and Python:

- In C++ the callback queue is associated to a particular node and this queue has to be processed by calling the blocking `ros::spin()` once or repeatedly calling `ros::spinOnce()`. The processing of these callback queue happens sequentially by means of a spinner thread but you can deploy multiple spinner threads to increase the throughput as well as use different node handles that process different subscribers. A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/ros-spinning-threading-queuing-aac9c0a793f).
- **In Python [each subscriber is running in a different thread](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2FTutorials.2FWritingPublisherSubscriber.The_Code_Explained-1)** and therefore there the only thing that `rospy.spin()` does is **block the main thread from returning** and thus keep the subscriber threads alive. You can also replace it with a `while` loop as explained [here](https://get-help.robotigniteacademy.com/t/what-is-rospy-spin-ros-spin-ros-spinonce-and-what-are-they-for/58).

In ROS2 the concept is similar but it is termed [executors](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Concepts/About-Executors.html) and further extends it with so called callback groups.

This means that you actually have to **register the subscribers and publisher with their callbacks inside a initialisation** routine and then you keep your node alive for the desired time, either with a `while` loop or `rospy.spin()`.

There is though no hard guarantee that all messages are actually processed. If your throughput is not sufficient (if your callbacks are executed too slowly) you will fill up the queue and eventually start dropping messages. If that is not what you need then have a look at the other communication methods - [ROS services](http://wiki.ros.org/Services) and [actions](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib). The other communication methods are though a bit more complicated.

---

Your code has several errors. You are lucky that Python is translated and not compiled and it never entered the relevant code parts..

- Functions like `subscriber`, `publisher` and `calculation` are never called inside your code, meaning the publisher and subscriber are never registered.
- `ros.Rate.sleep()` and `rospy.spin()` have nothing to do inside the `publisher` anc `calculation` routines. They are used to put the thread into an endless loop as long as ROS is running. This happens once inside a program only and that should be the main loop for clarity!
- `exact_pose` has actually to use the local values/class members inside the class like `self.line_pos` and not the subscribers like `self.line_pose_sub`. The subscribers are only executed when they receive new data. You can't force a subscriber to check for new data the way you seem to try it!
- `while` and `ros.spin()` does not work in combination. In C++ there is `ros::spinOnce()` but there is no equivalent in Python. You therefore need to use `while` and `rospy.Rate.sleep(d)` instead!
- `rospy.Rate.sleep` requires a duration as first input argument and can't be left void.
- You include a lot of libraries your code actually does not need.

---

I tried to restructure it and the following code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from math import cos,sin

class exact_pose():
  def __init__(self):
    # Set default values
    self.car_yaw = 0.0
    self.line_pose = 0.0

    # Initialise node
    rospy.init_node("emergency_procedure", anonymous=True)
    r = rospy.Rate(1)

    # Register topics
    self.car_yaw_sub = rospy.Subscriber('car/yaw',Float32, self.callback_car_yaw)
    self.line_pose_sub = rospy.Subscriber('line_pose',Float32, self.callback_line_pose)
    self.exact_pose_pub = rospy.Publisher('exact_pose',Float32, queue_size=10)

    # Repeat the following code in a loop
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      # Perform some calculation and publish to topic
      self.exact_pose = self.line_pose * cos(self.car_yaw) + self.line_pose * sin(self.car_yaw)
      info1 = Float32()
      info1.data = self.exact_pose
      self.exact_pose_pub.publish(info1)
      # Sleep for some time
      rospy.Rate.sleep(r)
    return;

  def callback_car_yaw(self, data):
    # Copy data to class
    self.car_yaw = data
    return;

  def callback_line_pose(self,data):
    # Copy data to class
    self.line_pose = data
    return;

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    # Create instance of class when node is called
    e = exact_pose()
  except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    pass
```

Put this code inside your code into your `.py`-file, open a new console and source the workspace with `source devel/setup.bash`, then start the `roscore`, open another console, source the workspace again and launch your Python node `rosrun <package> <node>.py`. Finally launch another console, source the workspace again and output the topic published by the Python node `rostopic echo /exact_pose`. If no other node is running this should output you `0.0` every second.